# Setting domain with vps

Tags: networking, ssh, browser, apache-http-server, web

I bought a domain and VPS. Every setup has been finished, but when I browse my domain, I get a “Connection refused” error message.

[image: “Connection refused” error message]

The customer support of my domain says it is because of ssh.
What is ssh? 
How do I get my domain working?

Comment: Secure Shell (SSH) has **nothing** to do with your browser being unable to connect to your domain.  This is likely an Apache (or whatever software you use to serve your website) configuration issue.